# How to access credentials in jenkins pipelineJob?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

How do I access the credentials from a secret file in the dsl file? I have credentials binding and job dsl plugins installed.

I have

```
pipelineJob(...) {
}
```